# Azure Pipeline Agent fails to use Proxy with Curl Error: CURLE_RECV_ERROR

Tags: linux, azure-devops, build-agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

When attempting to configure the agent on a RHEL7 machine via a proxy using 
`./config.sh --proxyurl <PROXY_URL>`, it gets stuck after prompting for Server URL and PAT.

Upon looking at the logs in the `_diag` folder, it looks like it is configured to use the Proxy in the statement - `Update proxy setting from '' to'<PROXY_URL_GIVEN_IN_ARGS>'`, but it is not able to connect to the server and keeps failing with `CURLE_RECV_ERROR`, there is no other information there.

The machine being used is running `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)` with `libcurl/7.29.0` and `OpenSSL 1.0.1`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft has misled you.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you ever find a fix ?

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/908